# Does WS_EX_NOACTIVATE affect the behavior of SetWindowPos?

Tags: windows, createwindow, setwindowpos

I have 2 monitors, A monitor is the primary monitor with a resolution of 3840x2160. B monitor is the secondary monitor with a resolution of 2560x1440. In my application, I use the following code to create a WS_POPUP style window and adjust its position.

```
window->Create(nullptr, "Title", WS_POPUP, WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
SetWindowPos(GetHWND(), NULL, x, y, widnow_height, window_height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
ShowWindow();
```

It works perfectly when I put the main window on primary monitor(A monitor) and create the WS_POPUP window and show it. However, I put the main window on the secondary monitor(B monitor) and create & show the WS_POPUP window, the window's size become smaller and it not appears in the correct position. Why?

More information: The strange behavior mentioned above disappeared when a SWP_NOACTIVATE flag added when create the WS_POPUP window:

```
window->Create(nullptr, "Title", WS_POPUP, WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
SetWindowPos(GetHWND(), NULL, x, y, widnow_height, window_height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
ShowWindow();
```

Just want to know the deep reason of the strange behavior.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows